# android studio 3 emulator, how to enable microphone input for speech recognition

Tags: android, emulation, speech-recognition

I am unsure how to enable microphone input in my emulator.  It is greyed out.  Is there some code that I can write that will let the microphone detect speech in the android studio (3.0) emulator?

My app works on a real phone, but I need to simulate other devices too. I can't buy all of the real devices.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can us Android x86 , It Support microphone , bluetooth, etc..
[android-x86_64-6.0-r3](http://bdownload.fosshub.com/programs/android-x86_64-6.0-r3.iso)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) as an alternative. It is no longer free for personal use and has builtin webcam and microphone set up for you. Most of the android developers use this as it is faster than AVD. There is also a [plugin](https://www.genymotion.com/plugins/) for android studio.

Comment: wow ok, I had thought that with the rise of android studio Genymotion was a goner.  Will give it a shot.